# Data Hiding and Objective-C synthesisers

Tags: objective-c

How exactly should attributes be declared if they are needed to be private and the language supports automatic getter/setter method creation?

Is the only way to override the automatically created getter or setter as needed?

Comment: if you need private only way is to class extension.

Comment: I dont think so. Private attributes can be declared within the implementation file.

Comment: How? using class extension using a category? isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

In the top of the .m (implementation) file:

```
// Private category on your class, declared at top of implementation file.
@interface MyClass ()
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * privateString;
@end

@implementation
... 
@end
```

These "private properties" are visible only within your implementation. 
**Please note** that ObjC has no facility for runtime access restriction. Other objects can still call your private getters and setters if they want to (although this will generate compiler warnings).

Comment: Thanks, yes I know this. My question is more on a design level. If it is said to be bad design to declare attributes in a header file, is the only way to access these via overridden getter/setter methods?

Comment: @Helium3: I don't quite follow. What's bad design about declaring (public) attributes in a header file? And what are you trying to avoid, exactly?

Comment: I guess what I am asking does not apply to Objective-C, will mark the question for deletion.

Comment: @Helium3: Maybe try giving an example of what you're thinking of?

Comment: @Helium3: Now you can not delete, Ben got votes.

Comment: Note that none of what Ben did was in the header file, nor would the storage or setters implied by `privateString` be visible outside the compilation unit.